# Configuring Bind dns with webmin

Tags: bind, ubuntu-12.04

I am new to VPS. I have recently bought a new VPS and trying to set up Bind DNS server on it using webmin.

My VPS provider has provided me with three IPS.

```
Main IP: 50.*.*.10
Additional IP 1: 50.*.*.11
Additional IP 2: 50.*.*.12
```

As I understand I need to setup a Master Zone and a Salve Zone on my VPS and then update the two namespace records on my domain providers site.

My question is,

Do I need to setup both Master and Slave Zones on my VPS (I only have one server)? or can I just create a master zone with two NS records (ns1 and ns2) using additional IPs and just use them to update domain settings on my domain provider?

Also, are there any good tutorials which I can use for this? I've googled a lot but failed to find a detailed tutorial, all I have found till now are few screenshots and short descriptions which don't make sense.

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need is to create the master zones and use your domain registrar to change the NS entries to your server.

You create a master zone for the *domain*, not the IPs. The only time you need this is for rDNS entries. The slave zone is when the daemon is simply acting as a failover for another DNS server.

Comment: Thanks, makes sense....I'll try this and see if it works.

Comment: What can I do if my DNS server fails? CAn I just forward queries to my ISP's DNS or Google public DNS?

Comment: You would need to set up a secondary DNS. Afraid.org has a free backup DNS feature that will work. I have this setup for my own personal domain. http://freedns.afraid.org/